# jQuery - unbind function doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function resizeMe(resizingFunction) {
    var resizeId;
    resizingFunction();
    $(window).resize(function() {
      clearTimeout(resizeId);
      resizeId = setTimeout(resizingFunction, 500);
    });
}

function scrollToText() {
    var scrollHandler = function() {
        console.log('handler')
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top-80
        }, 500);
    }

    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $('.jquery').bind('click', scrollHandler);
    } else {
        console.log('above 768');
        $('.jquery').each(function() {
            $(this).unbind('click', scrollHandler);
        });
        $('.jquery').unbind('click', scrollHandler);
    }
}
resizeMe(scrollToText);
});
```

So, it should run every time the window browser has changed its dimensions.

When the page is freshly loaded and its width is > 768 scrollHandler is not binded and it's desirable. When I change the size of the window to <= 768 of its width then the handler is bind to a click event and it works fine. But when I resize it again and the width is > 768 then the handler is still available (it shouldn't be). I tried to change the code in the condition block to $('.jquery').unbind(); so it removes every event binded to a selector then it works fine. The problem is I have some other click events binded to this element so I just want to remove this particular one. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `scrollToText` you are creating a new `scrollHandler` function (object) - so when you call `unbind('click',scrollHandler)` later in the same call that is the *newly created* `scrollHandler`, which hasn't been bound, so it can't be unbound (and you've lost the reference to the old handler).

Define `scrollHandler` outside of the `scrollToText` definition - you only need to define it once - and the rest of your code should work.

On another note, you mention that a few event handlers are bound.  Consider using event namespaces, like `bind('click.myScrollHandler',function(){...})` and later `unbind('click.myScrollHandler')`.

```
function scrollHandler() {
        console.log('handler')
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top-80
        }, 500);
    }

function scrollToText() {

    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        $('.jquery').bind('click.scrollHandler', scrollHandler);
    } else {
        console.log('above 768');
        //$('.jquery').each(function() {
        //    $(this).unbind('click', scrollHandler);
        //});
        $('.jquery').unbind('click.scrollHandler', scrollHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation - this make sense, your solution works as expected, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the resizeMe in window resize event:

```
//resizeMe(scrollToText);//This will be replaced by the following code
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  resizeMe(scrollToText);
}).resize();//trigger resize on load
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, still this handler is binded to a $('.jquery') selector

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
$(window).resize(function() {

resizeMe(scrollToText);

});

    function resizeMe(resizingFunction) {
        var resizeId;
        resizingFunction();
        $(window).resize(function() {
          clearTimeout(resizeId);
          resizeId = setTimeout(resizingFunction, 500);
        });
    }

    function scrollToText() {
        var scrollHandler = function() {
            console.log('handler')
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top-80
            }, 500);
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            $('.jquery').bind('click', scrollHandler);
        } else {
            console.log('above 768');
            $('.jquery').each(function() {
                $(this).unbind('click', scrollHandler);
            });
            $('.jquery').unbind('click', scrollHandler);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you using jquery? Media queries handles this things very easily.

```
@media (min-width:500px){/*Class name*/{/*properties*/}}
@media (max-width:499px){/*Class name*/{/*properties*/}}
```

Try this. Sorry for my english :/